# Keeping the ajax call alive when calling the Tornado server

Tags: python, comet, nonblocking, tornado

I'm trying to write my first tornado application.
The sample example for tornado, shows the below code, **however it seems that once the "MainHandler" function returns, the connection between the client & this server will be lost.**

I want the server to continuously push data, as and when it becomes available.
How does one keep this pipe open ?

On the client side I'm thinking of doing an ajax call. Will that work ?
I thought once the data is received, the ajax call ends.

Facebook does say that the client keeps a thread open with the server using tornado, hence I know it can be done, I think I'm struggling at some simple concept here..

```
import tornado.ioloop  
import tornado.web  
import time

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):  
    def get(self):  
        self.write("What happens after this call ?")  
    # while(True): time.sleep(5) <push more data># This would be ugly.. plus blocking(correct ?) 

application = tornado.web.Application([  
    (r"/", MainHandler),  
])

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    application.listen(8888)  
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

What is missing in my understanding ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use a websocket if you want to keep the connection open. Something like:

```
LISTENERS = []

class RealtimeHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        LISTENERS.append(self)

    def on_close(self):
        LISTENERS.remove(self)

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/', RealtimeHandler),
])
```

- http://dan.bravender.us/2010/1/15/WebSocket_Games_in_Python_with_Tornado.html
- http://thomas.pelletier.im/2010/08/websocket-tornado-redis/.

Comment: Thanks. That helped big time. I found the chat demo in the documentation and see the long polling in it. Websockets seem great.